# Successful connection to Google Calendar with Server to Server in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

So I wrote a scheduling tool, where my customers can book an appointment with me.
The next step is to link my tool to Google Calendar. This is to load the events from the tool into the Google Calendar and events, which I import into the calendar, back into my tool.
I've done all this through the OAuth 2.0 client interface.
Here is the problem that will re-authenticate when the token expires.
The customer should not be aware of the in my Google Calendar and therefore this method is not suitable.
(The customer's calendar is not required.

So now I've discovered that there is service key (server to server) for this.

Unfortunately, with my code I get no more events from my calendar

This is my code

```
      $client = new Google_Client();

      $client->setAuthConfig(public_path('.....json'));

      $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

      $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);

      $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));

      $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

      $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

      dd( $service->events->listEvents('primary')->getItems());
```

Comment: Have you tried following https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php ?

Comment: Yeah i tried both